# css3d rotating cube partially rotating

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am trying to create a rotating dice using just html and css i have the cube shape and it does rotate 45deg to the left on mouseover. this is my first experience with 3d css animations. i was following a tutorial but the code wasn't explained.
css code:

```
#container{
perspective:800;
perspective-orign:50% 110px;
-webkit-perspective:800;
-webkit-perspective-orign:50% 110px;
}
#cube{
position:relative;
margin:0 auto;
height:400px;
-webkit-transform:-webkit-transform 8s linear;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-webkit-transform:rotateY(-45deg);
}
#cube:hover{
-webkit-transform:rotateY(360deg);
-webkit-transform:rotateX(360deg);
}
@keyfremes myRotate{
from{left:100;}
to{left:100;}
}
.face{
position:absolute;
height:360px;
width:360px;
padding:20px;
background-color:rgba(50 ,50 ,50 , 0.7)
}
#cube .f1{
-webkit-transform:rotateX(90deg) translateZ(200px);
}
#cube .f2{
-webkit-transform:translateZ(200px);
}
#cube .f3{
-webkit-transform:rotateY(90deg) translateZ(200px);
}
#cube .f4{
-webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg) translateZ(200px);
}
#cube .f5{
-webkit-transform:rotateY(90deg) translateZ(200px);
}
#cube .f6{
-webkit-transform:rotateX(90deg) translateZ(200px) rotate(180deg);
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="cube">
             <img src="images/1.png" class="face f1" />
            <img src="images/2.png" class="face f2" />
            <img src="images/3.png" class="face f3" />
            <img src="images/4.png" class="face f4" />
            <img src="images/5.png" class="face f5" />
            <img src="images/6.png" class="face f6" />
        </div><!--close cube-->
    </div><!--close container-->
</body>
```

Any help would be appricated

Comment: Just a general pointer, you should include all of the vendor prefixes (not just webkit), and also put the spec version (unprefixed) at the end, so it takes precedence once it's implemented.

Comment: I just started to fiddle with this, and I think there are a lot of issues here, unfortunately I don't have the time to rewrite the whole thing (and I haven't done much with 3d transitions).   What I can tell you, is that you are partially defining an animation that isn't used.  you probably want `rotate3d` instead of the individual axes (especially since only one of those transforms will fire on `#cube:hover`, should be more like `#cube .f1`).  this line: `-webkit-transform:-webkit-transform 8s linear;` should be `transition`, not `transform`